# How can I SELECT the names of all groups a person belongs to using a JOIN instead of IN?

Tags: sql, join, subquery

Consider the following simplified example:

```
CREATE TABLE groups ( gid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(100) );

CREATE TABLE people ( pid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY );

CREATE TABLE people_groups (
    gid INTEGER NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT fk_people_groups_group
        REFERENCES groups(gid),
    pid INTEGER NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT fk_people_groups_person
        REFERENCES people(pid),
    CONSTRAINT pk_people_groups PRIMARY KEY (gid, pid)
);

INSERT INTO people (pid) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO groups (gid, name) VALUES (1, 'One');
INSERT INTO groups (gid, name) VALUES (2, 'Two');
INSERT INTO people_groups (gid, pid) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO people_groups (gid, pid) VALUES (2,1);

SELECT gid, name FROM groups WHERE gid IN (
    SELECT gid FROM people_groups WHERE pid = 1
);
```

This outputs:

```
1|One
2|Two
```

What is the correct `JOIN` for that last `SELECT`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT g.gid, g.name 
  FROM groups g INNER JOIN people_groups pg
       ON g.gid = pg.gid
 WHERE pg.pid = 1
```

---

Note: This is equivalent to your `IN` statement, because you specifically filter for only one person. If you filter for multiple persons, things are different. For example, assume that some person with `pid=2` is also in group 1 and you do the following SELECT:

```
SELECT g.gid, g.name 
  FROM groups g INNER JOIN people_groups pg
       ON g.gid = pg.gid
 WHERE pg.pid IN (1, 2)
```

This would return group 1 twice (in contrast to your `IN` solution, which would return each group only once). To solve this, you need to add the `DISTINCT` keyword after the `SELECT` *or* add `GROUP BY g.gid, g.name` at the very end of the SQL. You should keep that in mind if you use this answer as a general rule to convert `IN` to `JOIN`.

Comment: Two people can't come up with such similar answers and both be wrong. :D

Comment: Thank you for the followup explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This is the equivalent:

```
SELECT g.gid, g.name 
FROM groups g 
  INNER JOIN people_groups pg
  ON g.gid = pg.gid
WHERE pg.pid = 1
```

Comment: Or, even, three people can't come up with such similar answers and all be wrong. (See also comment to Heinzi's answer.)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT gid, name FROM groups 
NATURAL JOIN people_groups 
WHERE pid = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT g.gid, g.name
  FROM groups AS g JOIN people_groups AS p ON g.gid = p.gid
 WHERE p.pid = 1;
```

Comment: This makes intuitive sense to me but I am not very sure of my footing when it comes to SQL. Could you briefly explain why this is better than @Heinzi and @Oded's answers?

Comment: @Sinan: It's equivalent. In SQL Server, the `AS` keyword in front of table aliases is optional, as well as the `INNER` keyword in front of the `JOIN`.

Comment: This answer is no better or worse than the others. All of the answers provided so far will work.

Answer (score 1):

The answers given before are correct, but I'd like to note that you query will benefit from making the `PRIMARY KEY` on `(pid, gid)` (in this order).

This query:

```
SELECT  g.gid
FROM    people_groups pg
JOIN    groups g
ON      g.gid = pg.gid
WHERE   pd.pid = 1
```

will then be able to make `people_groups` be leading in the `JOIN` which most probably will make it much faster, since `pid` seems to be very selective in the link table.

Alternatively, you can create a secondary index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ux_peoplegroup_p_g ON people_group (pid, gid)
```

, or just

```
CREATE INDEX ix_peoplegroup_p ON people_group (pid)
```

if `people_groups` is `InnoDB`.

Comment: +1 Thank you for pointing out that the order of the columns in a composite primary key can matter. I did not know that at all.

Comment: @Sinan: Actually, the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint (which implies `InnoDB`) will create the second index automatically. However, this second index will have `3` columns in the key part, not `2` as in the `PRIMARY KEY`, and hence will be a trifle less efficient *for this query*. If you were to query for `gid = 1` and join with people, this layout would be ideal.

Comment: I am actually prototyping on SQLite right now. I don't know how it specifically behaves in this instance but it is good to know that the order can have an effect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT g.gid, g.name FROM groups g, people_groups pg 
WHERE g.gid = pg.gid and pg.pid = 1
```